# Spike in current limiter

Tags: ltspice, current-limiting

I'm building current limiter for my circuit, I saw a nice one in Maxim's document (Figure 2a): https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/2158

[image]

I need current limiting for 100mA, so I modified that circuit and simulated in LTspice:
[image]

It works, it limits current well, but there is some glitch/spike when power is switched on (current across R1):
[image]

Spike in detail (power is turned at 10μs, spike starts at 10μs):
[image]

I tried different transistors (Q1 and M1) but it didn't help.

What causes this spike?
Is there any problem in that circuit?
Or is it just some problem in LTspice simulation?
Is it possible to get rid of this spike?

Comment: The capacitor `C1` is the culprit there. It's meant to be filtering `M1`'s voltage, to avoid slight perturbations, but, in return, at startup, it charges briefly through `R1-C1-R2`. If you look at the time scale, the pulse is limited in both amplitude and time (~3ns), which is minor (unless your circuit is so very sensitive). If you move `C1` in parallel with `R2`, the behaviour will change.

Comment: I believe it's a simulation bug. A 400mA current going through 1k resistor would cause a 400V drop which in practice can't happen.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I accused C1 too. So I removed C1, and spike was still there.

Comment: @Chupacabras It wasn't possible to be \$C_1\$, as there's huge \$R_2\$ in the way, despite comments otherwise.

Comment: @Chupacabras You're right, I just simulated it and it's there. Then the other culprit is the zero series resistance of the load capacitor (which, in practise, will not be).

Comment: @dirac16 400mA is NOT going through 1k load resistor. 400mA is measured across R1 (sensing resistor). The 400mA spike travels through C2.

Comment: @Chupacabras sorry, I though R1 was the load!

Comment: Hold on, I just discovered it: it's the input source, which delivers the current to the charging capacitors through its (machine) zero internal resistance. If you add `Rser=1m Cpar=1m` to `V1`, everything changes.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I changed C2 for a real one (tantalum with 6Ω ESR). Didn't help. Spike is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my failed attempts in the comments, I point the finger to `V1`, who has (machine) zero internal resistance and is forced to deliver the charging current for the capacitors (through the other series resistances in the circuit). Normally, you'd have both a limited resistance from the input supply, and some capacitor at the input, so simulating that by adding `Rser=1m Cpar=1m` to `V1`, seems to solve it.

Comment: Well, `Rser=1m Cpar=1m` helped. I did not realize that I use ideal source, and that this is the culprit. Are those values real?

Comment: I meant to say it, but I forgot: there are other parasitic capacitances in the circuit besides the two visible ones, and they also contribute to spikes in currents.

Comment: @Chupacabras No, 1 mili-Ohm series resistance for an input source is an exceptional one, particularly for such low currents. But you will have a (dynamic) resistance, and you should place some capacitor, as well, the importance of which is clearly seen here. :-)